# get element from DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

hello i'm trying to get element from the DOM in angular directive.

this element:

[**click image**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzzbQ.png)

i'm trying to get this element by unknow id this is the code:

pass user object:

```
<dashboard user="user" action="pageSelect(name,pageNumber)"></dashboard>
```

in templateUrl directive:

```
<section>
<li id="Dashboard{{$index}}" ng-repeat="dashboard in user.NavigationMenu">
    <h3 class="PovDashboard">
        <i class="fa fa-tachometer"></i>
        {{dashboardName}}
    </h3>
    <ul class="povPages">

        <li ng-repeat="page in dashboard.Pages"> <i class="povIconRight fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></li>

    </ul>
</li>
```

and this is the problem:

```
  scope.$watch('user', function(newValue) {
            if (newValue !== undefined) {
                console.log(scope.user.NavigationMenu[0].Pages);

                var defaultDashboard = scope.user.DefaultDashboardID;
                console.log(scope.user);
                angular.forEach(scope.user.NavigationMenu,function(value,key){
                    if(value.ID === defaultDashboard){
                        console.log(key);

                        // i tried everything 
                        var s = '#Dashboard' + key;
                        var e = angular.element.find(s)
                        //e is  empty
                        console.log(e);

                        //i'm trying to do
                        //e.('.povPages').first().css("display","block"); 

                    }
                })


            }
        });
```

thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried this: `angular.element(s)`?

Comment: yes now "s" is not empty but that doesn't give me the element that i want:

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the jqLite wrapper `angular.element()` syntactically correct, i guess you should try with this:

```
angular.element(s).find('ul').css('display', 'block');
```

If you are not using jQuery then `.find()` will have a lookup at tagnames only.

From the docs:

> find() - Limited to lookups by tag name

---

Or better do it with angular way with `ng-show/ng-hide`:

```
<ul class="povPages" data-ng-show='isVisible'>
```

initialize `$scope.isVisible = false;`now in the `.$watch()` do this:

```
scope.$watch('user', function(newValue) {
    if (newValue != undefined) {
        console.log(scope.user.NavigationMenu[0].Pages);

        scope.isVisible = newValue != undefined ? true : false;
        console.log(scope.user, scope.isVisible);
    }
});
```

A sample demo:

```js
angular.module('demoapp', []).controller('demoCtrl', ['$scope', '$timeout',
  function($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.arr = [{
      text: "one"
    }, {
      text: "two"
    }];
    $scope.isVisible = false;
    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.isVisible = true;
    }, 2000);
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='demoapp' ng-controller='demoCtrl'>
  <div ng-repeat="obj in arr">
    <h1>see if list is visible == {{isVisible}} {{obj.text}}</h1>
    <ul ng-show='isVisible'>
      <li>should be visible after value change. {{obj.text}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @wrcron1 oops! that should be done with css method likewise.

Comment: i tried - > angular.element(s).find('ul').css('display', 'block'); but all my ul is display: none and as the pic show(up the page) i want child "ul" of '#Dashboard' + key" -> key can be 1 ,2 ,3 ... and so on

Comment: where i need to initialize $scope.isVisible = false; i did this in controller directive but is undefind then i move this to link in the first line after the if check.    i did this because the "ul" tag is in the templateUrl

Comment: Declare it in the controller instead which executes before directive.

Comment: i did   
Declare it in the controller   its dosent work then i tried inside the directive(what i wrote in comment above) also not working

Comment: @wrcron1 i have added a demo see if that lets you have an idea how to do it.